# deleting history in server using history -cw

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, sudo, command-history

I have deleted my history in server as a user  `history -cw`
Will this  delete  history for all users including superuser and will he see that I used  the  `history -cw` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, apparently, `history -cw` does not wipe the history file, only the shells view of it.

Comment: so how do I delete it COMPLETELY ?

Comment: and if so how can i  view my "deleted" history?

Comment: If bash, then 'rm ~/bash_history'.